# Can't understand why map() is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'd like to display "referti" from the db into my select dropdown, but i keep on getting the same error "this.state.referti.map is not a function". This is the code:

```
  componentDidMount() {
   this.mostraReferti(account.id)
  }

 mostraReferti(id) {
     axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/REFERTOs/' + id)
      .then(response => {
       this.setState({ referti: response.data }, () => {
         console.log("response.data", response.data)
            console.log("THIS.STATE", this.state)
          })        
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
 render() {
const refertiItems = this.state.referti.map((referti, i) => {
  return (
    <RefertiItems key={referti.hash_referto} item={referti} />
  )
})

<Label for="type" text="Referto" />
        <div className="custom-select">
      {refertiItems}
        </div>
```

now, response.data is an object, but when i store it in the state referti [ ], console.log ( "THIS.STATE") says it's an array, so it should be mapped, but i still get that "this.state.referti.map" is not a function. 
RefertiItems is :

```
    class RefertiItems extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            item: props.item
        } 
    }  

render(){
return (
    <div  className= "custom-select">
    <Label for="type" text="Codice Referto" />
    <select
      name="codiceReferto"
      placeholder="Selezionare Referto"
       onKeyPress={this.onEnter}     //allows you to move to the next panel with the enter key
      value={this.codiceReferto}
      onChange={this.handleInputChange}>
      <option default value="vuoto"></option>
          <option>{this.state.item.tipo_esame}- 
{this.state.item.data_esame}</option>
    </select>
    </div>
)}
 }
```

The weird thing is that at the begin i get the error and the page doesn't load, but if i reload the code the system render the page and i get 4 different select each one with a different value inside.

Comment: The type of `this.state` doesn't matter if you're trying to call `.map()` from `this.state.riferti`.

Comment: have you got a default state set? e.g: `state = {referti: []}` in your component?

Comment: what do you suggest?

Comment: You are  executing `mostraReferti` on didmount so after first render ?? That is the function that populates the state so on first render you don't have  that state defined or populated. Are you setting an initial state for `referti` ? like an empty array ?

Comment: The actual issue is try to use `map()` over an object so please check the response you are getting it is not an array at all.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like an issue caused by you not having an initial state. Add the following into your component and your issue should go away:

```
state = { referti: [] }
```

This will ensure that `.map` will initially pick up `[]` and not `undefined`

Comment: yes, i didn't pasted the first part of the code      
    class CredentialsPanel extends 
    Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
          referti: []
         }

Comment: @mikirug88 that error you reported is for sure map been used over an object .... try it in your console you will see the same one, so either change your response before updating the state or plan over your received data another way.

Comment: how can i turn the response into an array?

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional rendering, since `setState` is an `async` process it's not guaranteed that the data will be there when render is called, make the following changes and it should work:

Making sure that `referti` is iterable, the error is thrown because `map` only works for `arrays`. Also, make sure that `referti` is set to `[]` as the `initial state.`

**Example Sandbox**:  https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-worker-rk7z4?fontsize=14

Your state object:

```
state = {
   referti: []
}
```

Conditional rendering:

```
const refertiItems = this.state.referti.length > 0 && this.state.referti.map(referti => <RefertiItems key={referti.hash_referto} item={referti} /> />);
```

Comment: Actually that validation has no sense related to OP problem even if you loop over an empty array the error shouldn't appear so validate that has length doesn't solve the issue. If the state is undefined you will get `cant get length of undefined`  error

Comment: Check the edit, state is set to an empty array in the initial state object.

Comment: @Sasha null is a valid react component.

Comment: @Sasha What even? Doesn't sound like it? It's in the official react docs. Null works under the hood for many components in react, please check the facts before downvotes.

Comment: @Sasha what do you think is returned with the approach you have mentioned?

Comment: actually i don't get the error anymore, but it doesn't display the select anymore

Comment: @mikirug88 I have posted a code sandbox for your reference, check it out.

Comment: items.map is not a damn function eheh

Comment: What? Is the sandbox not working for you, because it's clearly working for me. Make sure you replace the variables with your own variables.

Comment: yeah the sandbox was working, my code is not working even if i changed the variables. I posted the sandbox with my original code, check it out, maybe you can find out the issue https://codesandbox.io/embed/recursing-sun-psiqm

Comment: Looking through it.

Comment: @mikirug88, the code is read-only, cannot make and view any changes to test it out. Check the edit and see the updated code for mapping through the array and returning the component.